# Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'undefined'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I'm trying to create a partial object that only has certain fields of the full object that meet a criteria.  However, I get the subject typescript error message when I try to assign the property.  I created a test module to illustrate the concept/problem.  Note that this is only to illustrate the problem.  It is not the actual code.

```
type FullObject = {
  id: number
  name: string
  active: boolean
}

type PartialObject = Partial<FullObject>

const myFullObj: FullObject = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'First Object',
  active: true,
}

const myPartialObj: PartialObject = {}

let k: keyof PartialObject

for (k in myFullObj) {
  if (myFullObj[k] !== undefined) myPartialObj[k] = myFullObj[k] // Error here
  if (k === 'name') myPartialObj[k] = myFullObj[k] // No error here
}
```

Note that it is only the first "if" statement that has the error.  After some research and trying various things, I worked around the problem by initializing the partial object to the full object and then deleting properties that did not meet a criteria.  Since this is a backwards way of solving the problem, I would prefer to create the partial object with properties that meet criteria.

Comment: `myPartialObj` is an empty object therefore you cannot access the keys and values in it as they are undefined. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: As I stated above, I'm trying to create a partial object that contains only certain fields from the full object that meet certain criteria.  My work-around in the real code was to first assign the full Object to the partial object and then delete fields that did not meet the criteria.

Comment: Well you need to be specific and state what `k` you want to set the value of for `myPartialObj` based on `myFullObj`.

Comment: The "for in" loop cycles through all the properties of myFullObj and sets the value of key to the key at each loop.  In my actual code, there are a very large number of properties in the myFullObj and the criteria that determines whether the value is to be copies is very complex.  I believe you are saying that the k parameter cannot be used on the lhs of the assignment as I'm trying to do.  Instead, it needs to be specified to an actual value (id, name, or active) in this case.  This would be extremely difficult in my case.

Comment: Therefore, it appears that initializing the partial object to the full object and then deleting keys in the loop for those cases that fail the criteria is the way to go. This is what I've done in the actual code. I was just hoping there was a more direct way of adding keys rather than deleting keys. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `if (myFullObj[k] !== undefined)` doesn't really make sense to me, the properties of the full object are never undefined.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Probably related:https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195

Comment: @Bergi I realize that `if (myFullObj[k] !== undefined)` but as I said, this was only meant to be an example of the error I was getting. Since full this condition will always evaluate to true, I could have skipped the condition and just wrote the assignment.  However, this is not the structure of my actual code, which has a complex conditional statement.

Comment: @MarkW. You could however just remove it for the simplified example, the type error persists.

Comment: @Bergi - Agreed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution.  It clearly illustrates what I am trying to do: if a criteria is met with a source object property, then copy that property into the partial destination object.  In this example I'm using "not undefined" as the criteria.  In the real code the criteria is more complex.

```
type FullObject = {
  id: number
  name: string
  active: boolean
}

type PartialObject = Partial<FullObject>

const myFullObj: FullObject = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'First Object',
  active: true,
}

let myPartialObj: PartialObject = {}

let k: keyof PartialObject

for (k in myFullObj) {
  if (myFullObj[k] !== undefined) myPartialObj = { ...myPartialObj, ...Object.fromEntries([[k, myFullObj[k]]]) }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(myPartialObj, null, '  '))
```

It seems that there must be a better way to accomplish this.  However, the example illustrates what is intended.

Comment: I ran into this today.  I found using `Object.assign(myPartialObj, {[k]: myFullObj[k]})` is acceptable to the compiler and avoids creating an extra object.